# how to use Google Cloud Speech API in node js with windows OS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

**I want to take text input from a speech by using Google Cloud Speech API, but I am unable to get it as the error occurs. What should I do or is there any other solution for speech to text in node js.
As I want to take text from speech and then split it into several words to match them from my library stored iMongoDBdb.**

My current code is this :

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const fs = require('fs');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'MY-PROJECT-ID';

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient({
  projectId: projectId,
});

// The name of the audio file to transcribe
const fileName = 'C:/Projects/audio/public/1.mp3';

// Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
const file = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');

// The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
const audio = {
  content: audioBytes,
};
const config = {
  encoding: 'LINEAR16',
  sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  languageCode: 'en-US',
};
const request = {
  audio: audio,
  config: config,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file
client
  .recognize(request)
  .then(data => {
    const response = data[0];
    const transcription = response.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');
    console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

and this error is coming:

```
$ node speech.js
ERROR: Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials:
Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/
accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\audio\node_modules\google-auth-librar
y\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:249:31)
    at step (C:\Projects\audio\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\g
oogleauth.js:47:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Projects\audio\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src
\auth\googleauth.js:28:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Projects\audio\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\a
uth\googleauth.js:19:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:3112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 3): Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credent
ials: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.googl
e.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
(node:3112) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is an authentication error.
Looking at your code sample, I see you're loading the audio file from `C:/Projects/audio/public/1.mp3` which means you're testing locally.

You likely didn't set up authentication in your local environment which is why node.js is return this error.

The guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs) shows how to set up implicit authentication for local testing.

Another option is to provide explicit serviceaccount credentials when creating the client. In this case you'll have to create and download a JSON containing the serviceaccount credentials. The whole process is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

Which one of these works best really depends on where you want to deploy your code. For GAE & GCP, the first option is easiest, as they  include the application default credentials in their respective environments. For Cloud Functions you **have** to use the first option as you cannot provide a JSON to authenticate the request.